# Linux as bootloader

Tags: linux, boot, bootloader

I'm up to something special. I want to seperate my single Windows 10 installation in multiple operating systems, each one with a single purpose. That's because my Windows 10 is full with games, programming tools, video editing tools, music recording tools, smart home tools and several other tools I don't even remember anymore. At some point this mess is freaking me out so I make a fresh install every 1-2 years. So the plan is, as said above, to split all mentioned "app groups" to an own os.

The complicated part is, that I often use my PC on the go with something like anydesk oder parsec.

So I figured out 2 possible solutions for that that will work but with downsides and 1 that I hope it will work.

1): A hypervisor My favorite solution for this is vmware ESXi. I would install every OS as a VM and map both, PCI devices and SSDs directly to those VMs. So this would be some kind of better multiboot-loader which I can also control from remote sites, as I just can start the VM I need. Downside is, that I can only run one VM at a time and the process of switching VMs is kind of nasty because of the PCI mappings.

2): Multiboot Here I found the bootmanager "rEFInd" which isn't just fancy but also highly customizable. So I will get a clean boot menu and just have to select which OS I want to boot at startup. The initial setup is a bit more difficult than the hypervisor part but that doesn't really matter. Downside to this is that I can not control this from remote, so I will also get to the same (default boot) OS with no option to boot another one.

3): A full Linux with GUI as bootloader As mentioned above, I don't really know if this is technically working, when searching about this I just find dual boot manuals for many OS combinations. My plan with this would be da bootable linux distro with gui, which one doesn't matter for me. I then want a function like select another OS to boot and then automatically unload the mentioned linux distro. Is that possible with shell scripts? With that it would be possible to select the booting OS even from remote site with connecting via anydesk or vnc.

Hope someone has an advice for this.

Comment: I believe this question is not narrow enough for Super User. It also cannot be narrowed down in a meaningful way. // I think what you want is a combination of 1 + 3: Run Linux on the host with Windows in VMs, possibly with GPU passthrough and maybe Looking Glass.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your advice. Looking Glass is definately an interesting solution, will give it a try. In general I just don't know where to ask something like this and was hoping that this is the right place...